# Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ssl, https

Когда у меня был http-протокол, всё работало отлично. Моё подключение к WebSocket-серверу:

```js
// frontend
   const ws = new WebSocket(
      'wss://transcribarium.com:8443'
   );

// backend
   const server = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8443 })
```

В итоге получаю следующую ошибку: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как связаны порты 8443 и 1289?

Comment: Немного ошибся :) Фронтенд-часть кода я взял с продакшн-сервера, бэкенд - с локального, а вообще на обоих серверах порты имеют значение process.env.WS_PORT, так что не уследил за значениями.

Исправил. Сейчас проверил, порты действительно совпадают на бэкенде и на фронтенде. Проблема явно не в этом

Comment: Ну так вы подняли *http* сервер на 8443 порту. А не *https*. https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md#new-websocketserveroptions-callback «To use an external HTTP/S server instead, specify only server or noServer»

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка - Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200